# Parse the cache-control header in PHP

Tags: php, cache-control

Was looking for a way to parse a string like `private, max-age=86400` into an array like this:

```
[private] => TRUE
[max-age] => 86400
```

Comment: Please leave a comment as to why this is a bad question. Parsing the cache-control header seems like a valid question to ask. My current answer isn't correct according to the comments, thus it has not been accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Parse the cache-control string into a key value array.
 *
 * @param string $cache_control
 *   The cache-control string.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Returns a key value array.
 */
function parse_cache_control($cache_control) {
  $cache_control_array = explode(',', $cache_control);
  $cache_control_array = array_map('trim', $cache_control_array);
  $cache_control_parsed = array();
  foreach ($cache_control_array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, '=') !== FALSE) {
      $temp = array();
      parse_str($value, $temp);
      $cache_control_parsed += $temp;
    }
    else {
      $cache_control_parsed[$value] = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return $cache_control_parsed;
}
```

Comment: `cache-control` allows for quoted strings (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2), so splitting on `,` won't work in general.

Comment: @Joe Do you have an example of a quoted string? It's not clear in the RFC what it would look like.

Comment: It's a niche case, and
[considered for removal](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/httpbisa/current/msg08290.html),
but `Cache-Control: private="set-cookie, last-modified"` would be valid.
More generally, [any extension](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.3) could use it (the `community="UCI"` in the spec is an example, although
not a pathological one).